javascript accessing data outside of function
I'm having trouble figuring out how to access my data properly. I have the following code bit
$.each(response.data.tree, function (i) {
  //We only want files
  if (this.type == 'blob') {
    //Initialize our variables
    var link = null,
      content = null;

    //Our link to pull data from
    link =
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkulikowski84/Code/main/' +
      this.path.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    let data = [];

    async function getCode() {
      // gets the response from the api and puts it inside a constant
      const response = await fetch(link);
      //the response has to be converted to text so it can be used
      const data = await response.text();
      //the addData adds the object "data" to an array
      addData(link, data);
    }

    function addData(link, object) {
      data['link'] = link;
      data['code'] = object;
    }

    //Calls the function that fetches the data
    getCode();

    console.log(data);
  }
});

When I print data to console log I see the following:

This is accurate with what I expect, however if I try to access the link or code directly with something like this:
console.log(data['code']);    

or
console.log(data['link']);    

I get undefined. How can I access all the code and links directly outside of my functions?

EDIT 6/7/24
After a bit of a struggle I happened to stumble upon a different way to so what I want and I thought I would share it on here. From my original code, I'm not sure if it was obvious but I was trying to build a custom function that allowed me to search key phrases on my github repo and pull that data onto my site. My initial code was very inefficient because it ran for each file so I would get the correct result, but it would run over 90 times.
With my new code it runs only 1 iteration and is also very fast and I believe much more efficient.
function handle(e)
{
//Variable to get our Active page
var ActivePage = $('div.page.active');
            
//Set the active page to show everything normally by default
ActivePage.find('li.back, li.dir, li.file').css('display', '');
            
//Set our variable to read text from our input
var Search_Code = (($('div.page.active').find("#Search_Code"))[0]).value;
//Configure our Search to be case-insensitive and search all occurances of the regular expression
var Search = new RegExp(Search_Code, 'gi');

//Reset the results each time you Search
jQuery('div[class="SearchResults"]').remove();

//Create our Div that will display our results on the active page
ActivePage.find('li.titles').after($('<div class="SearchResults">'));               
    
//If the enter button is pressed and search code is populated\valid
if((e.keyCode === 13) && (Search_Code))
{
    var _this = this;

    //First loop goes through all "branches" of the main repository
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/jkulikowski84/Code/git/trees/main?recursive=1',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response){
                                            
            //For each branch do stuff
            $.each(response.data.tree, function(i){

                //We only want files
                if(this.type == 'blob')
                {
                    //Setup our variable(s)
                    var link = null;
                                    
                    //Our link to pull data from
                    link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkulikowski84/Code/main/" + (this.path).replace(/ /g,"%20");
                                    
                    //Another Ajax call to get all the code from our files
                    $.ajax({
                        url: link,
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {},
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function(response){
                            if ((response).match(Search) || (link).match(Search))
                            {
                                //Hide the branches while results are populated
                                ActivePage.find('li.back, li.dir, li.file').css('display', 'none');
                                //Append results to out DIV
                                ActivePage.find('div.SearchResults').append($('<li class="SearchResults">' + link + '</li>'));
                            }
                        },
                        error : function(response){
                            if(console && console.log)
                                console.log('Request Error:', response);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        error : function(response){
            if(console && console.log)
                console.log('Request Error:', response);
        }
    });
}
return false;

}

FYI you should initialise data as an object ({}), not an array

I tried let data = {};, but for some reason I'm getting the same output. Saying it's undefined when I try it with link or code.
when I do console.log({data}); I see the output is a little different, but I'm still struggling to output the data[link] or data.link.

I didn't say that was a solution. It just didn't make sense for you to be adding properties to an array. The actual answer to your question can be found in the linked duplicates

I apologize, I'm not very good at JS so this is a learning process for me. I saw the duplicate threads. Some of them mentioned using json parse and stringify, but my code isn't in the form of a json file. I also tried structuredClone, but the output looks similar. I continue trying to figure this out.

You're focusing on the wrong duplicate
